# Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger Menu does not open with container underneath

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a bootstrap navbar and underneath some bootstrap content. However, the Hamburger Menu does not open when the viewport is small, and I wonder why.

If I remove the container which I put at the very bottom, underneath the navigation, things seem fine. But as soon as I add the bit again, I cannot open my navbar.

https://jsfiddle.net/0yu7u2yc/1/

```
<div class="header container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="brand col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 hidden-xs-down">
      <svg class="brand_logo"><use xlink:href="#brand_logo" /></svg>
    </div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Welcome<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown_angebot" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Pricing
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_angebot">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="softwareentwicklung.php">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="qualitaetssicherung.php">Another action</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com">
          Our Company
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" >
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="geschichte.php">History</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="karriere.php">Career</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="klienten.php">Clients</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="anfahrt.php">Get here<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.php">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" style="background-color:red; height:500px; margin-top:50px;">
        If I remove this (whole) bit, the navbar hamburger menu works again.
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.header {
  background-color: $background_header;

  .brand {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .brand_logo {
      width: 200px;
    }
  }

  .navbar-toggler {
        margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .navbar {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    background-color: $background_header;

    .navbar-nav {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;

        .nav-link {
          padding: 0 !important;
        }

        li {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;

          a {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
          }

          &:first-child a {
              text-align: left;
          }
          &:last-child a {
              text-align: right;
          }



          &:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-item:hover .dropdown-menu {
              display: block;
          }
          .dropdown-menu {
            // margin-top: 10px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
          }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content below header overlaps the hamburger menu. Try this:

```
.navbar-toggler {
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this in the fiddle? If so, then I cannot get it working *somehow*.

Comment: This is not the only solution. You do not know the requirement and this is therefore just one of many options!

Comment: @GeorgeWelder try the fiddle above :)

Comment: This just forces the button to the top without fixing the styling. The button would overlap anything you place in the content below.

Answer (score -1):

The hamburger-button element is not passing it's height onto it's parent (navbar). So the parent element has a height of 1px + 2x padding, which covers just the top part of the button. Notice how you CAN press the button in the top part. Add this to the navbar element css:

```
min-height: calc(40px + 1rem);
```

(40px is the height of the button and 2x .5rem for the padding).

Comment: In my opinion this solution is the the best one

Comment: I created a fiddle to try this out, but I cannot get it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/0yu7u2yc/3/

Comment: bootstrap is overwriting it somewhere. If added as a style attribute in the DOM it works: http://jsfiddle.net/0yu7u2yc/4